# how to store CGPoint in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Hi I am trying to store the move points in the `NSMutableArray` so I have tries like this

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];
if (MovePointsArray==NULL) {
        MovePointsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [MovePointsArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint]];
}
```

but this doesn't work how can i store these points in `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 18):

You should use addObject: in the last line:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];
if (MovePointsArray==NULL) {
        MovePointsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [MovePointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];

    if (MovePointsArray == NULL) {
        MovePointsArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint, nil];
    }
    else {
        [MovePointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint]];
    }
}
```

don't forget to retain / relase the array as you don't see to use a property accessor.

Best, you should alloc/init the array in your init method and then only do here :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *move = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint MovePoint = [move locationInView:self.view];

    [MovePointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an array using method `arrayWithObjects` you must also add `nil` as the last element of the array.

like so:

```
[MovePointsArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint], nil];
```

but to add an object to an existing array you should use `addObject` method

```
[MovePointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:MovePoint]];
```